# Swipe View to another layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, material-design

I have 12 .xml different layout for my app android. I want to make swipe view to go other layout. Do you have any suggestion, what should i use?? I try use fragment, but it should make a lot of java to set the layout and extends the fragment.

Comment: You can use `ViewPager`

Comment: Yes, i know that. And how to show different image with different text in the page?should i make few layout or use array??do you have any example??

Comment: You can use https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/Support4Demos for better understanding.

Comment: Ok, thnks very much @Faiyaz